# Manipulating Variable Given to Void Function in C

Tags: c, variables, program-entry-point, void

Is there a way to implement that sort of Code

```
#include<stdio.h>

void func(int a)
{
    a++;
}

int main()
{
    int a=0;

    func(a);

    printf("%d", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The changes I have made to the variable a dont seem to carry over when I reuse it in the main function. I think its done by using static variables but i cant figure out how to do it

Comment: Any C course teaches you this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about elementary material that should be learned by reading a C primer or textbook and working on course assignments rather than by asking on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

you need a 'c style pass by reference'

```
void func(int *a)
{
    (*a)++;
}
```

and

```
func(&a);
```

ie - pass in the address of 'a' as a pointer, then update it by dereferencing the pointer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would like to ask a follow up question. Would it be possible to do int b=1 and then a=&b instead. I tried it but it does not work, why is that?

Comment: @DlabaTlaba - update the question with what you tried

Comment: its fine i think i got it now. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is passed by copy (like in this case), changes made by your functions will not affect the variable in your `main`.
You should pass this parameter by reference.

So the solution must be like the following one

```c
#include<stdio.h>

void func(int* a) {
    (*a)++;
}

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    func(&a);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}
```